# Non-Exhaustive Error in When-Expression for a Sealed Class

Tags: android, kotlin, conditional-statements

I'm so stunned that I am getting a Non-Exhaustive Error when using a sealed classes with when-block.

This is the code that I am working with:

```
sealed class Vehicle

data class Car(val manufacturer: String, val model: String
) : Vehicle()

data class Bicycle(
    val manufacturer: String
) : Vehicle()

fun getVehicle(vehicle: Vehicle) =
    when (vehicle) {
        is Car -> "${vehicle.manufacturer} - ${vehicle.model}"
        is Bicycle -> vehicle.manufacturer
        
        //Error
        //'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'else' branch
    }
```

This is the error I am getting.

[image]

I have counter-checked with the latest [V1.8.22 docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) which clearly state the following:

> if when ***is used as an expression***, the else branch is mandatory, ***unless
> the compiler can prove that all possible cases are covered*** with branch
> conditions, for example, with enum class entries and **sealed class**
> subtypes).

I am of the view that all direct subclasses of a sealed class are known at the compile time and thus all outcomes on the when-expression are accounted for.

It is not a big deal to add the `else-block` but this comes as a shocker to me. I will appreciate your understanding on this.

Comment: It really must mean you have more subclasses. Try click "More actions...". It should offer "Add remaining branches" and if you click it you will see which ones you are missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code as you posted it compiles without errors. You probably have another `Vehicle` subclass floating around somewhere. You can find it either by selecting Vehicle and using the Hierarchy view (Ctrl-H on my setup) or by selecting the `when` and pressing Alt-Enter -> Add remaining branches.

Comment: Thanks for giving this a closer look. Thanks to you I copy-pasted the code into a different file and it compiled correctly. It turned out I had not indicated the `package name` on my initial file! Can you believe it?

Comment: Sure I can believe it, but I doubt that's the cause of the error.